# How do I select elements within a #document in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to set the background-image of the outer `<body>` tag in CSS:

```
<html>
 <body>
  ...
   #document
    <html>
     <body>
     </body>
    </html>
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

However, I can't even seem to select one of the `<body>` tags without affecting the other. They have no IDs, and when I try selecting via child selectors that `#document` complicates things (I don't even know what it is). If I try something like `body html body {...}`, the `#document` acts like a barrier that I can't get past, so it doesn't select the inner body tag.

Any ideas for how to select one of the body tags?

Comment: This would be invalid HTML to start with. Is the inner body in a iframe or frame?

Comment: What exactly is `#document`?

Comment: p:nth-child(1){..} will select the 1st 'p' element from a group of paragraphs.But I'm not sure about the situation here.

Comment: In all problems with styling/scripting always use DOM inspector, don't rely on the source code. HTML parsing rules are not always intuitive, not all source tags result in DOM elements and not all DOM elements have the corresponding source tags.

Comment: Validate your html by either making it an iframe. Is `#document` a node with an id of "document" or is it just text? Text should never be an orphan node - it should always be wrapped in some block level element `<p>` for instance.

Answer (score 17):

The given listing appears to be a DOM inspector view. In this case, `#document` doesn't refer to an arbitrary element with an id of "document" — it refers to the document hosted within an `<iframe>` (see [`Node.nodeName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-nodename)). You can see this in Firefox's and Chrome's DOM inspectors; in fact, you can even try it right now by pointing either browser to `data:text/html,<iframe>`, opening the inspector and expanding the `<iframe>` node. IE shows the nested tree as well, but without the `#document` marker.

If you're seeing the background image bleed from the host document into the iframe, that means the document in the iframe doesn't have its own background.

Selectors cannot penetrate multiple/nested document trees; they are localized to the context document. This means that you cannot target elements in a document hosted within an `<iframe>` from within the document that contains that `<iframe>`. If you need to apply styles to elements in a document within an `<iframe>`, the CSS needs to be directly applied within that inner document, and the selectors written as though you were working with just that document.

---

In the somewhat less likely event that the given listing is actual source markup rather than a DOM inspector view, and `#document` is in fact an arbitrary element with an id of "document", then your inner `<html>` and `<body>` elements have been written off, as an HTML DOM may only contain exactly one `<html>` and one `<body>` element at a time; these would be your outer ones, not the inner ones. In that case, you *could* try selecting `#document` and applying the background to that instead, but no guarantees that it'll work correctly.

Comment: I guess he's trying to access the parent from the iframe? No idea. *"I can't even seem to select one of the <body> tags without affecting the other"*... hmmm...

Comment: Yes, #document was an <iframe> element. Oh well...thanks though!

Comment: You can apply CSS from a parent to the contents of the child iframe - I've been doing it all day.

Comment: @Tom Chamberlain: It's on you to prove it.

Comment: @TomChamberlain I'd also be very interested in seeing how you did that.

Comment: @TomChamberlain Still would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

What you are thinking about would require there to be `<head></head>` tags inside the `#document` and `<iframe></iframe>` tags including `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Null.css">`. If you wish to alter this via embedding and altering then you will need jQuery, but there are no guarantees with jQuery because first of all, you need to know where to put it and second of all, it may not work if multiple things use the same ids/classes on the page with the `iframe` and the document inside the `iframe`.

Answer (score -3):

Using Jquery

You can use jQuery's .content() function to access it.

```
$('yourIframe').contents().find('#yourItemYouWantToChange').css({
    background: 'red'
});
```

Comment: CSS answer was requested, please don't make other assumptions on the used technologies.